# Next.js under a proxy with different path

Tags: node.js, proxy, next.js

Using next.js version `8.0.3` I don't know how to serve a custom server under a proxy with a different subpath.

I'm doing:

`npm run build && npm start`

In order to build and open the custom server.

And instead of open http://localhost:3000, I'm using a proxy with another subpath http://localhost:8000/example.

The proxy is simple, to reproduce it:

**proxy.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

const options = {
  target:'http://localhost:3000/',
}
const exampleProxy = proxy(options)
const app = express()

app.use('/example', exampleProxy)
app.listen(8000)
```

And then:

```
node proxy.js
```

However, when I open the http://localhost:8000/example url is loading the home page but without styles, statics, javascript... Anything...

How can I do it correctly?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a caveat, I'll start by saying that I don't believe NextJS plays nice with proxies, especially on a subpath.

That being said, the following should work, with limitations :

```js
const express = require('express')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

const options = {
  target:'http://localhost:3000/',
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/example': ''
  }
}
const exampleProxy = proxy(options)
const app = express()

app.use(['/example', '/_next', '/static'], exampleProxy)
app.listen(8000)
```

The pathRewrite option makes sure `/example/xyz` on the proxy redirects to `/xyz` on your NextJS server.

You need to proxy `/_next` (*or whatever you renamed your build directory to*) so that your page finds all the built assets (scripts, stylesheets, webpack chunks, etc.). If you inspect any of your Next's project pages you'll see that these assets links are absolute, hence the need to proxy that directory as well.

You need to proxy `/static` for the same reason, except that directory is meant to hold your static NextJS assets (images, etc.).

You'll also notice your page links in Next are usually absolute as well (I know mine are in all my projects).

All the above is the reason why I stated that, in my opinion, NextJS isn't really suited for a subpath proxy usage.

**Update:**

You can add the following config in your `next.config.js` file at the root of your NextJS project:

```js
module.exports = {
  assetPrefix: '/example'
}
```

This will prepend `/example` to all the built assets, so instead of `/_next/pages/xyz` you will link to `/example/_next/pages/xyz`. With this update you can remove the `/_next` proxy on the proxy side and your *buildable* assets (scripts, stylesheets, etc.) should still load.

Regarding the navigational (i.e. 'page') links within your NextJS app, as stated in my comment, you could setup your own version of `Link` and prepend your subpath:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

// for proxied server
const PROXY_PATH= '/example'
// for non-proxied server
// const PROXY_PATH= ''

export default MyLink = ({ as, children, ...props }) => <Link {...props} as={`${PROXY_PATH}${as}`}>{children}</Link>
```

You'd have to make sure all your `MyLink` components define an `as` prop. You *don't* want to change the `href` prop itself (the link as it *is*), only the `as` prop (the link as it *appears*).

Finally, for the `/static` assets, you'd just have to rewrite your static links inside your NextJS app, i.e. turn

```js
<img src='/static/mylogo.svg' />
```

to

```js
<img src=`${PROXY_PATH}/static/mylogo.svg` />
```

And the path rewrite on the proxy end should handle it correctly.
With this, you could define `PROXY_PATH` at the project scope in a separate config file or load it from an environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much to answer it! 

However, I guess that it is not the solution that I'm looking for :( ... Basically for two reasons: 

 (1) The idea of the proxy is to have different projects running on different subpaths, and we can have conflicts routing paths like `/static`... 

(2) Your solution works fine to load the page with static files, however, navigating with next.js is starting from `/` and not from `/example`.

I would like a solution touching only the next.js part, and not the proxy part. Is it not possible? :O

Anyway thank you so much! I appreciate a lot your effort.

Comment: @AralRoca I totally understand. As I said in my opening comment, I don't think NextJS plays nicely with a subpath proxy. There is however one thing you *could* do, and that would be to create your own `MyLink` component (inherited from Next's `Link`) and prepend your subpath to all links. But you'll still have to deal with the `/static` and build directories...

Comment: @AralRoca I've updated my answer with an additional configuration on the NextJS end, which would help with the build directory and the page links, but the `/static` assets directory remains an issue. Perhaps it could be handled with a custom server route on the NextJS side?

Comment: @AralRoca see my latest update for a possible (and simple) solution to the `/static` assets directory